# Escape dot in jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, validation, escaping

I'm using a jquery validation plugin as below

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        user.email: {         //the dot causes an error
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

I have a dot in the name of the user email input text field name and this causes an error. How do I escape this dot? It's not in a String so I can't use `\\`

The Html element looks like this

`<input type="text" name="user.email"/>`

[This](http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/) is the plugin I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot escape it, you must quote it, like this:

```
"user.email": {
```

Truth is, it's a best practice to use double-quotes (NOT single-quotes!) for all keys even when you don't need the quotes. This is to uniform with JSON, which **requires** the double-quotes.

Comment: Should have figured. Thanks